# about type deduction when perfect-forwarding

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T&& a) 
{
    cout << is_rvalue_reference<T>::value << endl;
}

struct O
{
};

O o;
foo(o); //T is deduced to o&,a is O&
foo(std::move(o)); //T is deduced to O,a is O&&
```

Hi,all.
Is there any way to make foo output 1(T is deduced to O&&)?

Answer (score 3):

No. No type will ever be deduced as an rvalue reference type. A deduced type is either an lvalue reference type or a non-reference type.

The *reference* type out in the "universal reference" construction is `T &&` (not `T`).